# Capture an image from a webcam “still pin”?

Tags: image-processing, camera, webcam, video-capture, wia

I'm looking for a way to capture a still image
from a webcam **without** streaming video from it.
(I have a USB bandwidth limitation and starting video will fail)

I could not find any examples how to read from a webcam's “still pin”.
C++ or C# code for Windows would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [GetImage Sample: Demonstrates the Windows Image Acquisition API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh90ebz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) - C++
- [WebCam Sample Project](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=378126) - VB.NET
- [Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) Code](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=439027) - C#
- [Using WIA for scanning](http://geekswithblogs.net/tonyt/archive/2006/07/29/86608.aspx) - C#

Answer (score 0):

check this out.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
and directshow sdk got examples for this. 
If you want a simple example just work. email me.